# How to save streaming data to Azure data lake?

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, apache-flink, azure-data-lake

I am using Apache flink for Streaming .I am taking data from Apache Kafka as a stream through flink and do some possessing and save the resulted stream in Azure Data lake.Is there any connector available in flink to dump the stream data in Azure data lake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flink supports all file systems that implement `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem`as noted here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.8/example_connectors.html.

So you should be able to set it up to output data to Azure Data Lake Store. Here is a blog that shows how to connect Hadoop to Azure Data Lake Store. The same approach in theory should work for Flink. https://medium.com/azure-data-lake/connecting-your-own-hadoop-or-spark-to-azure-data-lake-store-93d426d6a5f4